# Execution order of the code

Tags: c, pthreads

[sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG4eD.png)

Can anybody explain the execution order of this code?

I'm stuck on the `pthread_join` part while trying to understand how the code flow works:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 25

int thread_routine (int x)
{
    printf ( "I'm Thread %2d my TID is %u\n", x, pthread_self () );
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main ()
{
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];
    int x;
    pthread_attr_init (&thread_attr);

    for (x = 0; x < NUM_THREADS; x++)
    {
        pthread_create (&tids[x], &thread_attr, (void *)thread_routine, (void *) x);
    }

    printf ("Waiting for threads to finish\n");

    for (x = 0; x < NUM_THREADS; x++)
    {
        pthread_join (tids[x], NULL);
    }

    printf ("All treads are now finished\n");
}
```

Comment: Generally well formated question buddy. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: Your `thread_routine` has the wrong prototype, making the program undefined. If you're doing it right, you don't need to cast it.

Answer (score 0):

I see no problem with the execution order. The threads are created in order, execute on their own, and then you join them from first to last.

With a few modifications, the code works well on my machine, an old x86 Thinkpad running Linux (Kubuntu 16.04 x86_64). I compile with g++11.

Note that you need to be careful with the pthread_create arguments, and with handling the input to your thread function. x is an integer, and what you get as an argument is a pointer to void, so to get x back, you need to first send x:s address into pthread_create, and then retreive it by converting the void pointer to an int pointer and retreiving the int value the int pointer points to. Uff... It is much easier if you use the thin std::thread wrapper on top of pthreads.

You can also send in nullptr and skip creating the attr argument, since you are not using any non-default thread attributes.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 25

int thread_routine (void* p)
{
    int x = *((int*)p);
    printf ( "I'm Thread %2d my TID is %u\n", x, (unsigned int)pthread_self () );
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main () {
    pthread_attr_t thread_attr;
    pthread_t tids[NUM_THREADS];
    int x;
    int (*start_routine)(void*) = thread_routine;
    pthread_attr_init (&thread_attr);
    for (x = 0; x < NUM_THREADS; x++)
    {
        pthread_create(&tids[x], &thread_attr,
                       (void* (*)(void*))start_routine,
                        (void*) &x);
    }
    printf ("Waiting for threads to finish\n");
    for (x = 0; x < NUM_THREADS; x++)
    {
        pthread_join (tids[x], NULL);
    }
    printf ("All treads are now finished\n");
}
```